# Strange noise appears from my sound columns after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: windows-8, 13.10, noise

I have upgraded my Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10. I have also installed Windows 8.

I do not know if the issue is cause by the W8, but each time I switch from W8 to 13.10 this strange noise started.

The fix I have found is the following:

```
pulseaudio -k
pulseaudio --start
```

but I have found it very irritating to do this each time I have started the Ubuntu.

Has anyone idea how to fix this in long term?

Comment: I also have this issue, but I don't have Windows 8. It wasn't present in the previous version of Ubuntu for me. It looks like a configuration bug / software bug. Did you file a bug report on launchpad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be caused by incorrect Skype installation ( I have downloaded the Skype from its official web site).

The following line fix the problem permanently:

```
sudo sed -i 's/^Exec=.*/Exec=env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=30 skype %U/' /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

And [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/10/get-sound-working-in-skype-with-ubuntu.html) is the source of the fix, and also showing how to install Skype properly on Ubuntu 13.10:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install skype
```